# Trying to create a h1 in Angular.Js and there's a space after my last letter

Tags: angularjs

My code goes as followed

```
<h1> {{"Hello, " + "Angular!}} </h1>
```

and the output is: " Hello, Angular! ". as opposed to "Hello, Angular!"

Comment: `code` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='gemStore'>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> {{"Hello, " + "Angular!"}} </h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: There is a space after the last letter because there is a space after the closing `}}`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: No, sorry I just started today.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space.

```
<h1>{{"Hello, " + "Angular!"}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the space between `<h1><space>{{Expression}}<space></h1>`.
Change it as

**`<h1>{{"Hello, " + "Angular!"}}</h1>`**

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the space between the `<h1>` tags and the angular expression:

```
<h1>{{"Hello, " + "Angular!}}</h1>
<!-- instead of -->
<h1> {{"Hello, " + "Angular!}} </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

...Because you have a space after the closing }} :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks sorry for the bad question, I just started.